# Is it possible to deploy multiple Mobile Tractor Units?

Tags: eve-online

Is it possible in eve online with the upcoming rubicon changes to deploy multiples of the new mobile tractor unit deployable structures?

Comment: That is pretty much speculation as far as i know. Unless the dev's made a clear statement about this which i can't find with a quick search.

Comment: Please do not ask questions about unreleased patches and content. Even in a case like this where you can preview the patch on a test server, it is likely that what's being tested there and what will be released will differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Rubicon](http://eveonline.com) patch notes a mobile tractor unit cannot be deployed:

- within 40km of a control tower
- within 50km of a gate or station
- within 5000m of another mobile tractor unit

As such it should be possible to deploy multiple mobile tractor units at the same time (assuming sufficient cargo space to carry them + your loot as each tractor unit takes up 100m3)

Edit:

Having been on the test server and checked them out I can confirm that multiple tractor units can definitely be deployed together but, at least on the current test server build, will have a tendency to play tug-of-war with wrecks due to their required minimum separation.

Answer (score 2):

Salvaging is made easier with a noctis plus MTU.  Simply deploy the mtu's in each pocket and follow w/ your salvager...Parking the salvager next to the MTU.  No need to loot (as all loot is in one can) and all wrecks are all in one tidy lump removing the need for tractor beams and freeing up room for more salvagers.  I can target 9 wrecks at a time, I have 7 salvagers and 1 tractor making quick work of it all.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple mobile tractor units can be deployed but they must be 5000 meters away from each other.  There is a problem though.  The mobile tractor units by default will tractor the wrecks or containers closest to them.  So if you put one mobile tractor unit down then go 5000 meters and put another one down.  They will tractor each others already looted wrecks and disregard the other wrecks that are farther away.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that. However I did also notice that the autolooting still works as long as the unit touches the wreck, which is the primary reason I wanted the unit. I run a salvage alt so usually I tractor the wrecks in with the noctis, salvage with drones and let the tractor unit gather the loot to scoop in one go.